# First order ODE proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know where I can find a proof or a elaboration showing why every first order linear ODE can be expressed as:
$$a(x)y'+ b(x)y + c(x) = 0$$

Thanks.

Comment: this is just the DEFINITION of first order differntial equation in the most general case although perhaps it should be $ a(x) y' (x)+b(x)y(x)+c(x)=d(x) $ all the first order linear differential equation are of this way

Comment: Your equation is the same as mine.If we consider e(x) = c(x) - d(x) then we have a(x)y' + b(x)y + e(x) = 0. And by the way, there must be some elaboration from the differential form of expressing an ODE into the linear form of an ODE.

Comment: oh sorry :) , no there is by definition the MOST GENERAL first order differential equation

Comment: There's a reason someone named "linear" the ODEs that can be expressed in "a(x)y' + b(x)y + c(x) = 0" form.It is not arbitrary and it has to do with the property of every linear function or equation, which is the superposition ( additivity + homogeneity ) property.What i'm trying to link is the "a(x)y' + b(x)y + c(x) = 0"  form and the linear concept that says that the linear combination of any number of solution is also a solution when we are dealing with a linear equation ( an ODE is simply an equation ).

Comment: In fact i think i even found the answear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can consider that any first order ODE can be expressed by this equation f(y',y,x)=0.

Excluding the ODEs that cannot be solved explictly for y ( e.g: siny' + y' = x ) which are not linear for y anyways, we can represent any first order ODE as y' = h(y,x).

If h represents an affine map for y ,h:R²→R, we know :

h(y,x) = a(x)y + b(x)

The ODE can then be expressed as  :

y' = a(x)y + b(x)

Which is the same as :

y' + c(x)y + d(x) = 0

Which is the same as :

e(x)y' + g(x)y + j(x) = 0

Which is the wrong definition of a Linear ODE ( should be an affine ODE ).

Going back to y'=h(x,y) ...

If h represents a linear map for y ( holds the superposition property for the solutions y ) then we know :

h(y,x) = a(x)y

The ODE can then be expressed as :

y' = a(x)y

Which is the same as :

y' + c(x)y = 0

Which is the same as :

d(x)y' + c(x)y = 0

Which represents the true form of a Linear ODE, the only form of an ODE whose linear combination of solutions is also solutions.